Initialize WebRTC Call When Phone is Locked
I'm working on a React Native project where I’m implementing peer-to-peer calls using React Native WebRTC and React Native CallKeep. Everything works fine when the app is open and active, but I'm facing an issue when the phone is locked.
Problem:
When I receive a call while the phone is locked, I can answer through the native iOS interface (thanks to CallKeep), but the WebRTC connection doesn’t initialize. It seems that my WebRTC setup is only being triggered in a useEffect within my call.tsx component, which doesn’t run when the phone is locked.
For example, with apps like WhatsApp or Telegram, when receiving a call, I can answer directly from the native interface without having to unlock the phone. I'd like to achieve a similar experience with WebRTC and CallKeep, where the call connection initializes immediately upon answering.
What I've Tried:
Testing in active app state: Works perfectly.
Reviewing CallKeep setup: The native interface appears as expected.
Moving WebRTC initialization: I attempted to move some parts of the WebRTC initialization outside the useEffect, but I haven’t had success so far.
Question:
How can I ensure that the WebRTC connection is initialized properly when the user picks up the call from the locked screen? Is there a way to trigger the WebRTC setup directly when CallKeep answers the call, regardless of the app state?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions or examples that could help me resolve this!
